# Angular CLI rebuild process takes a long time

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-2

**Issue**:
i have an angular app with latest versions as of (June 2017)

once I make a small change or big changes in many files and save

the rebuild process kicks and **8 out of 10** times it takes **more than 60 seconds.** mostly in the assets folder.

I looked in SO and Github but none with a valid solution.

*PS: assets folder being large should not have impacted the performance as per comments from github.*

**OS**:
Windows 10

**Versions**:

```
@angular/cli: 1.1.0

node: 6.10.3

os: win32 x64

@angular/animations: 4.1.3

@angular/common: 4.1.3

@angular/compiler: 4.1.3

@angular/core: 4.1.3

@angular/forms: 4.1.3

@angular/http: 4.1.3

@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3

@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3

@angular/router: 4.1.3

@angular/cli: 1.1.0

@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
```

[image: screenshot of some built process results]

Comment: I used to have this issue as well. I simply uninstalled and reinstalled Node.js.

Comment: SOLVED: uninstall and reinstall node. thanks @Bean0341.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**: uninstall and reinstall node. thanks @Bean0341

removed 64bit version and installed 32Bit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using ng build and so I have checked and my project last 16 seconds to build. I would suggest to use this command to debug because it tells you the time that process take in your build.

```
ng build --verbose
```

more info here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build